# Trigger on multiple row result set

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I need to create a trigger notification for a low result on a survey response and it needs to be emailed.

A completed survey inserts something along the lines of:

```
Results_RecID   Question                    Points
1800            Rate our service            2
1800            Recommend us?               3
1800            Additional comments?        0
1800            <potential question 4>
1800            <potential question 5>
1800            <potential question 6>
```

The number of questions can vary depending on how the survey is set up.

Retrieve the latest set of results with:

```
SELECT  srd.points
  FROM  dbo.SV_ResultsDtl srd
 WHERE  (srd.SV_ResultsHdr_RecID IN (SELECT MAX(srd.SV_ResultsHdr_RecID FROM SV_ResultsDtl srd))
   AND  (srd.points < 3)
```

The trigger will fire for each row that is below 3.

Is there a way for this to fire only once, include all the results <3 in the notification, regardless of how many rows are returned?

Comment: Triggers are essentially stored procedures that are called when data is inserted, updated, or deleted.  You do not seem to be doing those operations.  Hence, I do not understand your question.

Comment: The data is inserted when the survey is submitted. This is a trigger for when that occurs. So it's clear, I've just listed the query I am using to retrieve the latest results which will be used in the trigger.

Comment: A trigger will fire once for each applicable statement. If an `INSERT` statement adds 42 rows then the `INSERT` trigger will fire once and the 42 new rows will be available in the `inserted` table. (Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) MSDN page.) You can process all of the affected rows and generate a summary action, e.g. insert a row in a table of queued email messages.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest sending emails from triggers. Two things that can go wrong: 1. Bad logic in a trigger means that a million emails are dutifully sent; 2. Failure to send an email can fail the trigger then fail the update. Some better ways are: 1. Use a trigger to insert into a queue which is subsequently actioned by something that sends emails; 2. Run a frequent job (i.e. every 5 minutes) that searches for unprocessed survey records. Both of these methods separate the emailing from the application itself

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to SQL SERVER, triggers are executed per statement not per row.It means that, if You use:

```
Insert into tableName (columns...)
values 
(val1, val2),
(val1,val2)
```

Then the trigger will execute once only when the statement is finished.I think that this is what You need.

One more thing, are You sure that this solution is safe?
You are assuming that max value is the value of current survey.It might not always be the case in some circumstances.

```
SELECT  srd.points
  FROM  dbo.SV_ResultsDtl srd
 WHERE  (srd.SV_ResultsHdr_RecID IN (SELECT MAX(srd.SV_ResultsHdr_RecID FROM SV_ResultsDtl srd))
   AND  (srd.points < 3)
```

Regards